Computing Jacobian matrix efficiently
How can the Jacobian of F(t,u)= Au - u/1+u be computed in MATLAB? A is a square matrix. How best to compute the Jacobian in Exponential Rosenbrock integrator?
function Jn = J(u)
   Jn = -A-1./(1+u).^2; 

end
I am thinking mathematically a scalar cannot be added to a square matrix. How can this be computed especially for an exponential Rosenbrock integrator?
